# Pythonのログ機能に関して

Tags: python, python3

お世話になります。
Python3.7でプログラムを作成していますが、ログ機能を導入しようとしてつまずいています。
とりあえず、例として、下記のようなプログラムを作成して、ログをファイルに出力しようとしているのですが、ログが出力されず、困っております。
どこが問題なのか、よければ教えていただけないでしょうか。
なお、ソースコードは2つに分かれていますが、両方ともログが出力されない状況です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

### ソースコード

#### test1.py

```
import logging
from logging import getLogger, FileHandler, Formatter
from test2 import *

def main():
    print("start")
    log = getLogger("test1")
    log.info("main initialized.")
    ret=test2()
    log.info("result=%d" % ret)
    log.info("finished.")
    print("result=%d" % ret)
    print("finished")

def log_init():
    hLogHandler=FileHandler("testapp.log", mode="w", encoding="UTF-8")
    hLogHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    hLogFormatter=Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(name)s (%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d):\n%(message)s", "%H:%M:%S")
    hLogHandler.setFormatter(hLogFormatter)
    log = getLogger("logger")
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log.addHandler(hLogHandler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_init()
    main()
```

#### test2.py

```
import logging
from logging import getLogger, FileHandler, Formatter

def test2():
    log = getLogger("test2")
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log.info("test2 initialized.")
    ret=1*2*3*4*5
    log.info("finished.")
    return ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test1.pyに関しては`logger`の名前が異なっていることが原因ですね。

```
log = getLogger("logger")
```

を

```
log = getLogger("test1")
```

に変えてみてください。

test2.pyに関しては`Handler`が設定されていないことが原因です。
試しに`test2()`の前に次の行を追加してみてください。

```
getLogger("test2").addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

これらの変更を施して実行してみると次のような出力が得られます。

```
start
test2 initialized.
finished.
result=120
finished
```

`logging.basicConfig()`を呼ぶだけでも`Handler`をよしなに設定してくれますが、`test1`側も影響を受けます。また、`addHandler`を何度も呼ぶと、その回数だけログが重複して出力されますので、呼び出す個所にもご注意ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました。「logging.basicConfig()」は試していたんですが、filenameでファイル名を指定しているにもかかわらず、なぜかコンソールに出力されてしまっていたので、諦めてしまいました。もう1度ちゃんと調べてみます。

Answer (score 1):

`getLogger` で取得したロガーがそれぞれ異なっているのが問題です。 一旦以下のようにすることで `test1` 内部のログを取得可能です。

また、 `test2` についても、モジュールとして構成する場合は通常 `__name__` として参照することで同様にログを出力することが可能です。

```py
import logging
from logging import getLogger, FileHandler, Formatter

def main():
    print("start")
    log = getLogger(__name__)
    log.info("main initialized.")

def log_init():
    hLogHandler=FileHandler("testapp.log", mode="w", encoding="UTF-8")
    hLogHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    hLogFormatter=Formatter("%(levelname)s - %(name)s (%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d):\n%(message)s", "%H:%M:%S")
    hLogHandler.setFormatter(hLogFormatter)
    log = getLogger(__name__)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log.addHandler(hLogHandler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_init()
    main()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。「test1.py」に関しては、ご提示いただいたコードでうまくログが出力されるようになりました。しかし、「test2.py」は、「log = getLogger(__name__)」に変更してもログが出力されないようです。